# The entire parametrization of leaves of singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations

What is  an example of   an  entire non constant  holomorphic  function $\gamma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}P^2$  such that the  image  of  $\gamma$ is a leaf of  a  singular  holomorphic  foliation  of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$  arising from  a  non  linear  polynomial  vector  field on  $\mathbb{R}^2$  or $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Moreover,  is  it  true  to  say  that every leaf   of a singular holomorphic  foliation of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is  the image  of  an entire  function defined on  whole $\mathbb{C}$.

The  above  question is included  in the  following  post  but  it did  not  get  an answer.  So I  ask  it  as  an  independent question

[The error in Petrovski and Landis' proof of the 16th Hilbert problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171988/the-error-in-petrovski-and-landis-proof-of-the-16th-hilbert-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: $dy=y^2$ can be integrated by quadratures. The solutions are homographies.

For your second question: no it is not true. By the uniformization theorem, the universal covering of a leaf $L$ is either the Riemann sphere $\bar {\mathbb{C}}$, the complex line $\mathbb C$ or the unit disc $\mathbb D$. The latter is the generic situation for generic polynomial foliations. Now, any entire, surjective map $f : \mathbb C\to L$ would realize a holomorphic cover. Because $\mathbb C$ is simply connected, it means that  $L$ has $\mathbb C$ for universal cover.

Comment: Thank you. The  first  part of  your  answer, I think, correspond  to the  vector  field  $x'=1, y'=0$  but  we  require  a  non linear term.(As  I  indicated in my  question). The  second  part  of  your  answer is  very helpful  for  me. But  am I  mistaken to  think in the  paper  of  Petrovski landis  they  wote  in the  first  parts  of  their  paper, "every  solution is  an  entire  holomorphic  function from  C  to CP^2.(In  their  paper AMS  translation)?

Comment: May  I  ask  you to  give  comment  to the  linked  question, too? Do you  have  a  downladed version of  the  talk of  Ilyashenko? I  have  difficulity  for  multiple  watching of this  video.

Comment: Yes it's the constant vector field to start with but you twist the $y$-component by a homography so that the foliation is no longer linear in the original coordinates. Ok, that's cheating. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: So  you  consider  $\gamma(t)=-1/t$  as a  an entire  holomorphic  map  from  C to  CP^1. yes?

Comment: But of course ! Why wouldn't it be ?

Comment: In [your question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237877/is-there-an-entire-solution-for-the-van-der-pol-equation?lq=1) you already obtained an example of polynomial vector field with no entire leaf, I don't really know what can be added. Since I don't have Petrovski and Landis paper, I don't know what they claim.

Comment: To  what  extent the  entire  assumption in the  paper of  Petrovski  Landis paper was  essential in their  proof?  Moreover  do  you  have  a  downloadable  version of  the  Ilyashenko  video?

Comment: I  had  asked  a  question for existence  of  an  entire  solution  for  vander pol  but  in that  question I  was  considering  C to  C^2 not  CP^2.

Comment: I think you are reffering to this already question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237877/is-there-an-entire-solution-for-the-van-der-pol-equation

Comment: The argument of Alexandre Eremenko works also for $\mathbb P_2(\mathbb C)$ since the argument only regards a bounded disk : if the function were to assume an infinite value on that disc, you could change the target coordinates so that the new function wouldn't.

Comment: From what  reference  you  read the  proof  of  genericity  of hyperbolic  leaves  of  SHFC, as  you  indicated in your  answer?could  you  please  mention that reference?

Comment: I don't know offhand, but I think it's folklore. Try Il'Yashenko paper on topological rigidity ? I'll try to find a renerence.

Comment: Thank you  very  much  for  your  help  and  interesting  answer.