# A complex limit cycle not intersecting the real plane(2)

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, counterexamples, limit-cycles

Inspired by [this question and the  counter example provided in its answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293197/a-complex-limit-cycle-not-intersecting-the-real-plane) we ask:

> Is there a  polynomial vector  field  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that after complexification of the equation, the  corresponding singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ possess a regular  complex leaf  $L$ whose holonomy is nontrivial  and $L$ does not intersect the real part  of $\mathbb{C}^2$? That is $L$ does not intersect $\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid im(z)=im (w)=0\}$.

**Note:** The  counter example in the above linked post shows that this  situation can occur if the  coefficient of polynomial vector  field are  complex. But what  about if the  coefficients are real?

Comment: This case is the same as your example in the complex version of the question. Just consider $$z′=w+(z^2+w^2+4) \\ w′=−z+(z^2+w^2+4)$$.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  Yes. Many thanks  for this comment.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  Now I think that the  example i provided in the linked question is somewhat a  fake example, in the sense that the leaf is an algebraic leaf. now I am thinking to  find  an  algebraic  vector  field  with  a  non algebraic complex limit cycle  not intersecting the real plane(both real or  complex coefficents). As we know a  generic algebraic vector field  does not have an  algebraic leaf.So in this new formulation is the question still an obvious question?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the algebraic nature of the leaf is relevant here. But I already was wrong on this question ;)

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  No  but your  comment  was interesting. May be  it is  an indirect  motivation to consider the following  example: $\begin{cases}x'=y-x^2\\y'=-x \end{cases}  $  Now  what about the curve $e^{-2y}(y-x^2+1/2)=i$?  What  can be said about its  holonomy?Is it nontrivial?  I  appreciate your  comments  to this  question.

Answer (score 1):

This note contains an affirmative answer to the question

https://maco.lu.ac.ir/article-1-86-en.html