# Infinite number of closed geodesics on distorted sphere

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geodesics, closed-geodesic

I would appreciate a reference to support this statement that
appears under the **Geodesic** entry of the
[CRC Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.routledge.com/The-CRC-Encyclopedia-of-Mathematics-Third-Edition---3-Volume-Set/):

> "no matter how badly a sphere is distorted,
> there exists an infinite number of closed geodesics on it.
> This general result, demonstrated in the early 1990's,
> extended earlier work of Birkhoff, ..."

Comment: Bangert, 1993, https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0129167X93000029?journalCode=ijm       Refers to J. Franks, 1992, Inventiones

Comment: good survey  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5417.pdf

Comment: Incidentally, there is [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04017.pdf) paper claiming a proof of existence of infinitely many geometrically distinct closed geodesics on arbitrary closed Riemannian manifold of positive dimension. I do not know what's the status of the result.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - On page 27 we find "Theorem 6.14 (Main Result). Every closed Riemannian manifold M admits infinitely many geometrically distinct, non-constant, prime closed geodesics."  There is no hypothesis on the dimension of M (to rule out the point and the circle). Trying to understand the first sentence of the proof (the definition of X given before 6.5) left me no wiser.

Comment: @SamNead: Maybe I will post a question about the current status of the (notorious) conjecture on closed geodesics. The above reference claims a solution. By now the paper is 4 year old. Of course, especially during the pandemic, refereeing may take long time...

Comment: @MoisheKohan  In this regard please see this question too

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152513/number-of-disjoint-simple-closed-geodesics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will Jagy answered my question:

> Bangert, Victor. "On the existence of closed geodesics on two-spheres." *International Journal of Mathematics* 4, no. 01 (1993): 1-10.
> [doi](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129167X93000029).

"...one obtains the existence of infinitely many closed geodesics for every Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$."